# Passar value do select para o javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

quando o usuario escolhe determinada opção no select, vai aparecer outro select, ou seja, se estado civil for casado aparece o conjugue.

Preciso que o value do select passe para uma variavel, essa variavel vai se comunicar com o javascript e ele vai fazer a ação de esconder insira o código aqui

```js
window.onload = function exibir($pegavalor){
    var valor = $pegavalor;
    
    if(valor == true)
            document.getElementById('optionOculto').style.display = "block";

        else if(valor == false)
            document.getElementById('optionOculto').style.display = "none";
    };
};
}
```

```html
<select name="civil" id="civil" onchange="exibir($pegavalor,'optionOculto')">
  
  <option value="0"<?=($pegavalor = 0)?> >
    -- Selecione --
  </option>

  <option value="1" <?=($pegavalor = 1)?> >
      Casado
  </option>

  <option value="2" <?=($pegavalor = 0)?> >
    Solteiro
  </option>
  
   <option value="3" <?=($pegavalor = 0)?> >
    União Estável
  </option>
  
   <option value="4" <?=($pegavalor = 0)?> >
      Divorciado
  </option>
   
  <option value="5" <?=($pegavalor = 0)?> >
    Outros
  </option>
</select> 

 <?php
  echo $pegavalor;
  if($pegavalor == 1){
   $pegavalor = true;}
  else{
   $pegavalor = false;}
 ?>

<div id="optionOculto">
  Nome Conjuge <input type="text" name="n-conjug"/>
  
  Valor da Renda <input type="text" name="v-renda"/>
  
  Outras Renda <input type="text" name="o-renda"/>
</div>
```

Comment: É necessário passar uma variavel para coletar os valores do "value",  ID do select (Estado civil) e o ID do select (escondido), pois tenho muitas condicoes como essa, criar um js pra cada seria inviável

Comment: Tem uns php no meio, como assim?

Comment: Estou tentando, não deve estar certo rsrs, não manjo muito

Comment: Pensei que fosse erro na hora de copiar o código, desculpe. De fato, é necessário remover as partes `<? ... ?>` e adicionar um listener ao event "change" do select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa parte está errada:

```
window.onload = function exibir($pegavalor){
```

Você está definindo a função `exibir` para ser executada no event `onload`, que é no carregamento da página.
No entanto, a função `exibir` deve ser executada sempre que o valor do `<select>` for alterado, ou seja, em seu evento `change`.

É necessário também remover as tags php, e não é necessário a variável `$pegavalor`. Você consegue definir valores arbitrários para um elemento HTML através dos [`data-attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). Poderia ficar assim:

```
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

function exibir() {
    var exibirDetalhes = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.exibir;
    var detalhesEl = $(this.dataset.detalhes);

    if (this.value == "1")
        detalhesEl.style.display = 'block';

    else
        detalhesEl.style.display = 'none';
}

$('#civil').addEventListener('change', exibir);
$('#outro-select').addEventListener('change', exibir);
...
```

Ainda é preciso fazer as correções mencionadas no HTML:

```
<select name="civil" id="civil" data-detalhes="#optionOculto">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
  <option value="1" data-exibir="1">Casado</option>
  <option value="2" data-exibir="0">Solteiro</option>
  <option value="3" data-exibir="0">União Estável</option>
  <option value="4" data-exibir="0">Divorciado</option>
  <option value="5" data-exibir="0">Outros</option>
</select>
```

Estou dando preferência ao método `selectEl.addEventListener('change', exibir)` (em vez de inline js, por ex. `<select onchange="exibir()"`) porque nesse caso acho mais interessante deixar o JS bem separado do HTML (lógica separada da apresentação).

Comment: Se tiver algum problema, esse exemplo está funcional http://codepen.io/rodorgas/pen/NRZAwp